# Using condformat with Knitr to create a table on a pdf?

Tags: r, knitr

I've found the package condformat, that easily creates coloured tables from data.frames.

You can run one of its examples.

```
data(iris)
library(condformat)
condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) +
  rule_fill_discrete(Species) + 
  rule_fill_discrete(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length,expression = Sepal.Width > Sepal.Length - 2.25, colours = c("TRUE" = "#7D00FF")) + rule_fill_gradient2(Petal.Length)
```

[image]

I can use it within a markdown document if I generate an html.

But I'm not able to use it to generate a pdf.
I've tried both with knitr and with rmarkdown.
Knitr produces the error:

```
Overfull \hbox (22.4968pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 62--62
Missing $ inserted.
```

and many

```
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
```

And when I try to embed the code within a rmarkdown chunk it doesn't produce any error but the output it's just a single column with many numbers, without colours.

I've tried both with results='asis' and without it.

How can I get these tables when creating a pdf with a Rnw Knitr?

Sometimes I get similar results with xtable or or ztable but the former is very difficult if you want to selectively colour cells, and the latter doesn't work well sometimes.  For example I'm not able to print numbers in scientific format inside a ztable table.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason you're having a hard time getting `condformat` to print to PDF is because it doesn't support PDF output.  It only supports HTML output (unless I'm not seeing something in the manual).

So if you'll forgive some shameless self-promotion, I'll recommend the `pixiedust` package to you.  The downside is that `pixiedust` doesn't have some of the neat features, like automatic color selection or gradients that `condformat` has, but those are things that are going on my bucket list right now.

The upside of `pixiedust` is that it supports both HTML and LaTeX/PDF output using the same syntax. The RMarkdown script below will produce a table similar to the example from `condformat`, and you can switch between Knit PDF and Knit HTML to get the same presentation.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: "May 6, 2016"
header-includes: 
- \usepackage{amssymb} 
- \usepackage{arydshln} 
- \usepackage{caption} 
- \usepackage{graphicx} 
- \usepackage{hhline} 
- \usepackage{longtable} 
- \usepackage{multirow} 
- \usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor} 
- \makeatletter 
- \newcommand*\vdashline{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\$\dabar@\dabar@\dabar@\$}} 
- \makeatother
---

```{r}
library(pixiedust)
library(RColorBrewer)
data(iris)

output <- iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]

dust(output) %>%
  sprinkle_table(pad = 3) %>%
  sprinkle(
    cols = "Species",
    bg = c(rep("rgb(249,118,110)", sum(output$Species == "setosa")),
           rep("rgb(1,186,56)", sum(output$Species == "versicolor")),
           rep("rgb(98,156,255)", sum(output$Species == "virginica"))),
    recycle = "rows"
  ) %>%
  sprinkle(
    cols = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"),
    rows = which(with(output, Sepal.Width > Sepal.Length - 2.25)),
    bg = "#7D00FF"
  ) %>%
  sprinkle(
    cols = "Petal.Length",
    bg = cut(output$Petal.Length, breaks = 9,
             labels = brewer.pal(9, "BrBG")) %>%
           as.character(),
    recycle = "rows"
  ) %>%
  medley_bw()
```
````

Comment: That's not what I was looking for, but nice to know it.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm not sure what it is you're looking for.

Comment: The main thing I'm looking for is the ability to easily colour tables.  And the way to force condformat to output something usable to generate a pdf through knitr

Comment: Beside that, I've tried your package with a simple lm output and I get this message: Error in .Call("dplyr_resolve_vars", PACKAGE = "dplyr", new_groups, names) : 
  "dplyr_resolve_vars" not available for .Call() for package "dplyr"

Comment: `pixiedust` certainly has that ability.  I'd be interested to see your code so I can diagnose the problem.  I'm not having problems on my `lm` objects.